# trying to configure the ruby environment but I issue the command of echo 'evaluation "$(chef shell-init bash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile It does nothing

Tags: chef-infra

After I installed the workstation I went to the next section " Getting Started". I was trying to configure the ruby environment but when I issue the command of

```
echo 'evaluation "$(chef shell-init bash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

It does nothing.  Help!

Comment: Please link to the guide you are following and show your exact chef version and operating system. Please add the command you are entering and the exact output of it to your question. Also, please be sure to enter commands exactly as shown (as it should likely be `eval` rather than `evaluation`)

Answer (score 1):

When executing `chef shell-init` it will print what needs to be added to your `.bash_rc`

This will work for you

```
echo 'eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it modify the contents of your profile? Check the contents of the file to see if the chef script init was added:

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

After that, check to see if your ruby path is to the chef one:

```
which ruby
```